# send F11 key in code behind in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I want to use full screen mode in silverlight application but while using silverlight's own full screen feature, keyboard is disabled. So i can use browser's F11 functionality to make the application run in full screen mode. 
Can anyone please suggest how to send keys in silverlight??

Comment: You're asking how you can have Silverlight transmit the `F11` keystroke to the hosting browser application? (FYI, in my experience with IE, it will actually capture browser shortcuts before having them sent to Silverlight, so it may work there "out-of-the-box"... it's a feature, not a bug!)

Comment: I actually have a button in my application, clicking on which application goes into full screen mode but as described earlier, keyboard doesn't work. So the only alternative to work in full screen mode is to send this F11 key on that button click event.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're in trouble. AFAIK, browsers do not allow programmatic access to window functionality; that is, they won't allow an untrusted application (like Silverlight, or on-page JavaScript) to invoke its "fullscreen" command.

There is also no way to "fake out" the browser as though the user sent the keystroke.

Both of these are serious security issues which is why it's not really possible.

*Plausibly* with Silverlight running as a trusted application *in-browser*, it may leverage some of the P/Invoke functionality to get around it, but I suspect that's going too far in your case.

EDIT: By the way, if you *are* able to host your Silverlight app as a [trusted application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), then keyboard events are still permitted. However, since you've tagged the question as `Silverlight-4.0`, I do believe you'll have to upgrade to Silverlight 5 to take advantage of the functionality.

Comment: @user2091061 Just stumbled upon a tidbit. Turns out a fullscreen API has some specification and implementation on _some_ browsers. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/ Works for me in Firefox, but not Internet Explorer. Perhaps you can have Silverlight call out JavaScript methods in the hosting browser to leverage this API.